# How would I make a cancel button work like the "X" button?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, cancel-button

In my XAML file, I have a window and I am trying to make it so the behavior is the same whether the user clicks the "X" button, or if he clicks the "Cancel" button.

My abridged code is below:

```
public partial class Dialog : Window
{
    .
    .
    .

    private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    { 
        e.Cancel() = true; //Works as expected
    }

    private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel() = true; //Compile error
    }
}
```

So I realize that my problem is that RoutedEventArgs does not have a Cancel() method. Does anyone know how I can make RoutedEventArgs work more like CancelEventArgs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the IsCancel property of the button to True.

Comment: Thank you very much! You have saved me hours of headaches.

Comment: It is not working for me somehow. I have exactly same situation, but even if I change the IsCanel to true, the e still contains no Cancel();