# Cancel button closing window

Tags: c#, wpf

Thanks for reading my thread.

I am trying to insert a cancel button that basically does the X button for a window.

Here is the code from [How would I make a cancel button work like the "X" button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881760/how-would-i-make-a-cancel-button-work-like-the-x-button). I have exactly the same situation

```
public partial class Dialog : Window
{
    .
    .
    .

    private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    { 
        e.Cancel() = true; //Works as expected
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel() = true; //Compile error
    }
}
```

Here is the xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="ExperimentSettingsViewer.TemplateName"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Template Name"
        Height="120"
        Width="300"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/ExperimentSettingsViewer;component/Button.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/ExperimentSettingsViewer;component/Window.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/ExperimentSettingsViewer;component/Border.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox Name="tbName"
                     Margin="3"
                     Text="{Binding Path=NewName}" />
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="right">
                <Button Name="btnOK"
                    Content="OK"
                    Width="75"
                    Height="30"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    Margin="3"
                    Click="btnOK_Click" />
                <Button Name="btnCancel"
                    Content="Cancel"
                    Width="75"
                    Height="30"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    Margin="3"
                    Click="btnCancel_Click" IsCancel="True" />
            </StackPanel>

        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

However, I follow the solution in that thread, and set the IsCancel of the buttom to true, but still, there is no Cancel() methods available for my button.

I am wondering is there anything I missed? Or how can I make my cancel button work like a X button. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Button.IsCancel` property does not automatically close your window.  All it does is allow you to use Escape to "press" the button.  You still need to call `Close()` in your click event handler in order to close the window.

Because of this, there is no `Cancel` property for that event.  If you don't want to close the window, just don't call `Close()`.